# How to get coming weekdays from given date using moment in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using moment package in my node module.Here I have coded to get next given day's date from given start date.But it returning the current week days. How to resolve that.
To be more clear
Start Date is - 2015-01-01 . I would like to get 'Monday' date and 'Tuesday' date from start date. I should get 2015-01-05 , 2015-01-06 . But am getting 2014-12-29 , 2014-12-30. It returning the corresponding week days date.[image]

Comment: please share your code through jsfiddle to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 0):

This will return the month

```
moment("2015-01-05").format("MMM")
```

This will return the day

```
moment("2015-01-05").format('ddd')
```